# What is this kitchen utensil called?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call [this](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpropp)・[thing](https://www.google.se/search?q=diskpropp&tbm=isch), that keeps the water in the sink while I do the dishes?

Comment: I think it is a plug!!

Comment: !! ?? Really ?? !!

Comment: @BlessedGeek Yep, really. I think I was confused because a `plug` (the only term I could come to think of) to me is something that is pushed into a hole (like the one on the picture below), whereas the `sink stoppers` normally used where I live (Sweden) are of [the type that covers the hole](http://malmo.matvaran.se/ica_produkt/i_582569835.jpg).

Comment: Did you try google translate first?

Comment: @Mitch I did. It suggested the nonsensical [`disk stopper`](https://translate.google.com/#sv/en/diskpropp)...

Comment: Do a google images search for the thing you're thinking of in your own lanuage, then change to English, to get the same images but now with the English labels.

Comment: @Mitch That's an interesting idea, but what are the labels you are referring to? (I did a number of reverse images searches with Tineye and Google's “search by image” feature, but they gave nothing this time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a [sink plug](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=964&q=sink%20plug&oq=sink%20plug&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1583.6123.0.6234.19.14.5.0.0.0.463.1253.13j4-1.14.0....0...1ac.1.55.img..0.19.1272.Pa0kRllYk84) or a [sink stopper](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=964&q=sink%20stopper&oq=sink%20stopper&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1526.3501.0.3592.14.10.1.2.2.0.130.646.8j1.9.0....0...1ac.1.55.img..2.12.650.uo9X7LFj9kk).

Answer (score 1):

One of your images is this:

[image: Sink plug]

...which is called a ***plug.***

> A circular piece of metal, rubber, or plastic used to stop the plughole of a bath or basin and keep the water in it:
>   *she pulled out the plug and got out on to the sodden bath mat*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plug#plug__6)

[Image via Google, apparently from http://kokthansogreta.nu/]